# Classic ASP: I'm getting a type mismatch error when I shouldn't

Tags: asp-classic, type-mismatch

I have a function for turning HTML encoded text back into HTML.  It works great normally, but for some reason, I try to use it on some text today, and get the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'UnChkString'

/manage/solutions_delete.asp, line 22
```

The line I am using this function on is:

```
<%= UnChkString(solution_desc) %>
```

The `solution_desc` variable is:

```
&lt;p&gt;Here is a description of what this solution is all about.&lt;/p&gt;
```

The field the database is pulling the `solution_desc` from is a text field.

My UnChkString function is:

```
Function UnChkString(string)
    UnChkString = Replace(string,"[%]","%")
    UnChkString = HTMLDecode(UnChkString)
End Function
```

The HTMLDecode function is:

```
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim I
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , "&")
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&rsquo;", Chr(39))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))
    For I = 1 to 255
        sText = Replace(sText, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))
    Next
    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
```

**EDIT**

I've even tried:

```
<%= UnChkString(CStr(solution_desc)) %>
```

with no luck.

Comment: @bfavaretto `<%= UnChkString(solution_desc) %>`

Comment: Maybe you are getting `NULL` from the DB? Does the error happen with the example string you posted?

Comment: @bfavaretto The string I posted is what I get from the database.  That is what is written if I do not try running it through the function.

Comment: Very strange. I can run it normally on my machine, no errors!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes its best to just re-read the error very carefully.  Consider this chunk of VBS:

```
 DoStuff("Hello World")
```

Since `DoStuff` is not defined nor is there an `Option Explicit` I get:

> Error: Type mismatch: 'DoStuff'

Your error is: `Type mismatch: 'UnChkString'`.   Its not complaining about the parameter being passed its complaining about `UnChkString` itself.  My guess is you have committed the most basic of VBScript programmming goofs, you don't have a `Option Explicit` at the top of you code.  This is a must.

For reasons unclear form the code you posted so far the code at the point that `<%= UnChkString(solution_desc) %>` is being executed the script engine does not have a function `UnChkString`, hence the error you are seeing.  I suspect that inclusion of `Option Explicit` will reveal the problem (as well as forcing you to `Dim` all your variables).

Comment: I started responding saying that I wish it was this easy, but that the functions script is auto-loaded into each page, but then checked anyway.  This was the reason.  My functions script was not included in this particular page.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Anthony's opinion that you should be using Option Explicit at the top of your ASP pages.

I suspect the cause is a missing or malformed include file

I can replicate this with the code below where I either remove

```
<!--#include file="include-functions.asp"-->
```

or malform the call by changing it to

```
<!-#include file="include-functions.asp"-->


include-functions.asp
<%
Function UnChkString(string)     
UnChkString = Replace(string,"[%]","%")     
UnChkString = HTMLDecode(UnChkString) 
End Function 
%>


index.asp
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--#include file="include-functions.asp"-->
<%

Dim solution_desc
solution_desc = "&lt;p&gt;Here is a description of what this solution is all     about.&lt;/p&gt;"


Function HTMLDecode(sText)     
Dim I     
sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))     
sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , "&")     
sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))     
sText = Replace(sText, "&rsquo;", Chr(39))     
sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))     
sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))     
sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))     
For I = 1 to 255         
sText = Replace(sText, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))     
Next     
HTMLDecode = sText 
End Function 

%>
<%= UnChkString(solution_desc) %> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix it, You need to first check if the string has the char in it, do this..

```
Function HTMLDecode(byVal sText)
    HTMLDecode = sText
    If Instr(HTMLDecode,"&amp;") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    If Instr(HTMLDecode,"&amp;") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&amp;" , "&")
    If Instr(HTMLDecode,"&quot;") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    If Instr(HTMLDecode,"&rsquo;") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&rsquo;", Chr(39))
    If Instr(HTMLDecode,"&lt;") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    If Instr(HTMLDecode,"&gt;") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    If Instr(HTMLDecode,"&nbsp;") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))

    For I = 1 to 255
        If Instr(HTMLDecode, "&#" & I & ";") Then HTMLDecode = Replace(HTMLDecode, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))
    Next
End Function
```

And..

```
 Function UnChkString(vStr)
     UnChkString = vStr
     If Instr(vStr,"[%]") Then vStr = Replace(vStr,"[%]","%")
 End Function
```

That should fix your `Type Mismatch` issue.  Don't ask me why, it just works.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `string` to `vStr` and modified slightly.

Try this way:-

```
Function UnChkString(vStr)
    vStr = Replace(vStr,"[%]","%")
    UnChkString = HTMLDecode(vStr)
End Function
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I had tried that already too (different variable, of course) with no luck.  Tried it again anyway, but still same thing.